# Load local html files using array

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

here is the code of table view

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    self.navigationItem.title=@"sample";
    servicesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [servicesArray addObject:@"1"];
    [servicesArray addObject:@"2"];
    [servicesArray addObject:@"3"];

    urlsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [urlsArray addObject:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [urlsArray addObject:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    [urlsArray addObject:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
}
```

these are deployed in another page called details 
here is the code of details page

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"urlstring %@",urlString);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

here instead of urls i want to load my local html files.

Comment: Please don't double-post questions.

Comment: but that question itself not having answer . then why we can't post duplicate

Comment: please use the new syntax, its easier to read.

`urlsArray = @[ @"http://www.google.com", @"http://www.yahoo.com", @"http://www.facebook.com" ];`

Comment: Then why don't you add the local file path to array instead of weburl ?

Comment: @oliver Atkinson I dont think he asked for advice on how to syntax his code.  It is not up to you to tell him how to write his code

Comment: @SoupBoy Duplicate questions are actively suppressed on SO when asked by different authors; when asked by the same author more emphasis should be given especially as it's possible for the author to edit their original question.